# How to get awesome_print to work in pry/ruby-debug in running app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I super love awesome_print and ruby-debug but I can't get them to work together. AwesomePrint returns HTML for formatting but I'd it seems like ruby-debug and pry don't like multi-line output so I always end up with a complete mess. This is what it looks like when I run ap from pry or ruby-debug (in a running app).

```
pry(#<#<Class:0x000001117f2f58>:0x000001117ef560>)> ap @user
=> "#<User:0x000001111de888> {\n<pre>:id</pre><pre> =&gt; </pre>\n ... snip ...}"
```

Has anyone had any luck getting awesome_print to work in ruby-debug or pry on a running rails app? Am I just doing something wrong? I would also be happy with multi-line pp, at least that would be a huge upgrade.

Thanks!

Comment: do you use "irb" once you on a break point?

Comment: what version of pry are you running? if you're not running 0.9.2 try upgrading; also just try typing `@user` as recent versions of pry use pretty_print + coderay which is almost as good as awesome_print IMO

Comment: Thanks banister, that was totally right. I hadn't realized pp was throwing me.

Answer (score 1):

Specify awesome_print in your Gemfile. Bundler runs things in its own context (not exactly know how or why this is done)