# Why is my pry not using coderay to make output pretty?

Tags: ruby, irb, coderay, pry

Why is my [pry](http://pry.github.com) not using coderay to make output pretty?

I don't get pretty awesome_print-style object/output printing... just boring irb-style one-line output.

This question implies it should Just Work: [How to get awesome_print to work in pry/ruby-debug in running app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736315/how-to-get-awesome-print-to-work-in-pry-ruby-debug-in-running-app)

**update:** actually it works for hashes, but not for, say, an ActiveRecord object.

Answer (score 0):

if `awesome_print` is otherwise working but just not working on `ActiveRecord` objects, then i assume that `awesome_print` does not support `ActiveRecord` objects (dont know much about active record here sorry)

Comment: Oh I see -- I don't have awesome_print installed, I thought it was redundant with Pry. But maybe I should have it installed.